# Antlr4 clearDFA affects performance a lot

Tags: java, antlr4

We are using antlr4 in Java, and noticed the Memory leak problem, because of the static cache and DFA array.

We have first tried

```
lexer.setInterpreter(new LexerATNSimulator(lexer, lexer.getATN(), lexer.getInterpreter().decisionToDFA, new PredictionContextCache()));
parser.setInterpreter(new ParserATNSimulator(parser, parser.getATN(), parser.getInterpreter().decisionToDFA, new PredictionContextCache()));
```

But the memory leak was still happening.
We tried to clear the DFA after every parsing process

```
parser.getInterpreter().clearDFA();
lexer.getInterpreter().clearDFA();
```

Also tried setting new default DFA (copying the code from generated antlr code), the memory leak seemed stopped. But the performance just got really bad!

Any suggestions?
I wonder if antlr consider putting allowing DFA and cache to be setup in other places (like redid or memcache). So we could have more control over the cache/DFA policy.

Comment: Do you have a grammar and examples to look at? My experience with grammars that perform worse with caching happens with grammars that have ambiguity. But it is hard to say without seeing the grammar.